# JqueryDatepickers and datatables not initiating when I load content into a div from another page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, so, on 1 page (with my header and footer(with the javascript stuff)) I am loading content from another page into a div `content`, now when I directly view the div being load from the external pages all the datatables work, as do the datepickers etc, but when I am on the page I want to populate the data with (from the otherpage) not of that is working, I have the code at the very end, so the page has load,

**page being loaded**

```
<div id="inner_main_content">all the content I want on the other page will be here</div>
```

**page loading:**

```
<div class="content"></div>
```

I am using jquery.load with selectors for the `inner_main_content div` here's an example of my datatable code:

```
    // <!-- data tables !-->
    $('#employment_history').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
        "bLengthChange": false
    });
```

No errors, etc, as states, it's iniating when directly viewing the page being loaded, but not when it's been loaded, how can I fix this?

My load for example:

```
$("#content").load("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/edit_profile" + " #inner_main_content");
```

Please note: I can not put my datatables inside the load because I have too many and would be repeating the same datatables over and over, I am trying to do something like this if it exists: (psuedo code)

```
$('content').on('live', function(){
     //all my datatables, datepickers etc here
});
```

Comment: initialize datepicker and datatablejquery after another page load complete. 
Like if you are calling another page data via ajax. On success, after dump data initialize jqery.

Comment: Yup, I could do that, but that would require iniating it more than I'd like, I'd trying to find a way to delegate it so I only need to initiate once.

Comment: If you don't need the dataTable or datepicker for the initial content, you can do what @KushalVora suggested. You don't have to init the scripts twice, only after the async content was loaded.

Comment: Share your javascript code when you initialize it. Otherwise we can't help you, even with a bounty in the middle

Comment: I use multiple hence why i am trying to delegate it

Comment: *"I am using jquery.load"* Can't see that. Post enough code for this to make sense. No bounty will help if no-one except you can see what you're doing.

Comment: can you give all the datatable a class to load them with one command only or you have different parameters for each?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the load complete function of jquery like:

```
$( "#content" ).load( "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/edit_profile" + " #inner_main_content", function() {
    alert( "Load was performed." );
    //fix table
    $('#employment_history').dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
         "bLengthChange": false
    });
});
```

Comment: please read the note at the bottom on the OP if that's possible, thanks.

Comment: I did, but I don't get why you need to do it double this way, you should only load the dataTable in this way. There is no way that javascript knows when all content is ready in the general case, because you can always load stuff asynchonously.

Comment: Because when a user updates a form, or if the hash in the url matches, or visits the link it will use the load, I have 4 loads per each url, which means I'd have to iniate the same datatable 4 times.

Comment: Ok, that is not so nice, but there is no other way to solve that using load.

Answer (score 0):

scripts rendered on a page are lost when jquery load is using section of the pages, you need to attach on load event completion an handler to render all you jquery controls, check http://api.jquery.com/load/  section **Script Execution**

```
$( "#content" ).load( "<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>user/edit_profile" + " #inner_main_content", function( response, status, xhr ) {
  if ( status != "error" ) {
     $("#employment_history").dataTable({
        "bFilter": false,
         "bLengthChange": false
    });
    $("input#datepiker").datepicker();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem.. i used setTimeout() method for the page load..  just use setTimeout() for those pages which have datepicker fields.. may be this will help you too..